# How to remove YYYY-MM-DD from datetime, leave HH:MM, and convert it to EST

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm building a stock researching program that utilizes an API and I can't seem to figure out how to remove the years, months, and day from the datetime. The problem with this is that date is a user input so I tried using f strings but it did not work. The script itself works fine its just that I have plans on automating this so it transfers to an excel sheet by itself and I'd like for the time to be in EST as that is what the stock market operates on.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'h': [6.50, 6.63, 6.50, 6.50, 6.55, 6.55, 6.55, 6.57],
                   'date': [2022-04-22 08:46:00, 2022-04-22 09:14:00, 
                            2022-04-22 09:41:00, 2022-04-22 09:45:00, 
                            2022-04-22 11:54:00, 2022-04-22 11:57:00, 
                            2022-04-22 12:06:00, 2022-04-22 13:00:00]

ticker = input('Ticker: ')
date = input('Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
data30 = requests.get(api_30).json()
data10 = requests.get(api_10).json()
data1 = requests.get(api_1).json()

data30['results']
data10['results'] 
data1['results']

df = pd.DataFrame(data1['results']) #Results grabbed from API
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], unit = 'ms')#To convert to datetime 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])#Label new column 'date'

pmhightime = df[(df['date'] > f'{date} 07:30:00') & (df['date'] < f'{date} 13:30:00')]#To display premarket hours only
pmhightime = pmhightime[['h','date']]#Change dataframe to only include 'h' being high and 'date'
pmhightime = pmhightime[pmhightime['h'] == pmhightime['h'].max()] #To find the row that has the highest value
pmhightime = pmhightime[['date']]#Change dataframe to only have date

print('Premarket High: ', pmhightime.to_string(index=False,header=False)) #To get rid of index and header
###Output /// for ticker I will put DOGZ and date 2022-04-22
Ticker: DOGZ
Date (YYYY-MM-DD): 2022-04-22
Premarket High:  2022-04-22 09:14:00
###The output I'd like to have
Ticker: DOGZ
Date (YYYY-MM-DD): 2022-04-22
Premarket High: 5:14:00 AM
```

Comment: Provide a sample of your dataframe using `df.head().to_dict()`. Also include your expected output

Comment: @not_speshal I don't know how to do that I'm very new to programming and 95% of this program is trial and error combined with stackoverflow. I'll try and figure it out and update the post

Comment: Include the output of `df.head().to_dict()` in your post. Then put in a table showing what your output should look like.

Comment: @not_speshal I included the df at the top and my desired output is at the very bottom

Comment: Time zone rules depend on the date, so you'll have to convert the tz *before* you remove the date. Actually, I'd suggest to keep the date and create a new, time-only column, to not loose any information.

Answer (score 0):

You could surely use momentjs library it provides us with a wide variety of functions that we can use to fulfill our needs in that particular use case.
Here is its website: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo
import pytz

def parseDate(date):
  return datetime.strftime(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(date),'%H:%M')
```

datetime.strftime(date,'%H:%M') formats it in HH:MM

pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(date) localizes the date

Comment: I don't mean to bother you but where would I input this in my code I don't fully understand all the rules

Comment: add it to the beginning of the script.

then, when you have a date you want to format, use `parseDate(mydate)`

Comment: I have them all added but my output is the exact same do I have to change the variables inside?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column with just the time formatted as string:

```
df["time"] = df["date"].dt.strftime("%I:%M %p")

>>> df
      h                date      time
0  6.50 2022-04-22 08:46:00  08:46 AM
1  6.63 2022-04-22 09:14:00  09:14 AM
2  6.50 2022-04-22 09:41:00  09:41 AM
3  6.50 2022-04-22 09:45:00  09:45 AM
4  6.55 2022-04-22 11:54:00  11:54 AM
5  6.55 2022-04-22 11:57:00  11:57 AM
6  6.55 2022-04-22 12:06:00  12:06 PM
7  6.57 2022-04-22 13:00:00  01:00 PM
```

Comment: One last question how do I adjust the time column to be EST

Comment: Aren't all your dates in EST already?

Comment: No they aren't converted, all my dates come in unix and I convert them to datetime I'm sure its really easy to convert them but I just don't know how